# Is there an easy way to publish std_msgs::Time from cli?

Tags: ros, std-msgs, ros-kinetic, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to publish the current ROS time to a topic from the command line. Is there some way to achieve this?

EDIT: Focusing my question a bit more-- I'd like to publish the equivalent of ros::Time::now() from cli.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275143/is-there-an-easy-way-to-publish-std_msgs::time-from-cli?/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-11-07**:
Can you add why you can't subscribe to the `/clock` topic directly?

**Comment by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on 2017-11-08**:
It's for testing a particular node that subscribes to a std_msgs::Time msg. I realize there are other ways to do this, but I was hoping there was a quick way to specify a "now" message from the cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit2: ah, I'd completely misunderstood you.

> I was hoping there was a quick way to specify a "now" message from the cli.

`rostopic pub` should actuallys support this.

I'm not sure how well it is documented, but `rostopic pub --substitute-keywords ..` allows you to use a `now` keyword that should be substituted with the current time as a timestamp:

```
  -s, --substitute-keywords
                        When publishing with a rate, performs keyword ('now'
                        or 'auto') substitution for each message
```

I haven't checked, but you should be able to use something like:

```
rostopic pub -s -r 1 /some_topic std_msgs/Time 'now'
```

That publishes `ros::Time::now()` at a rate of 1 Hz.

---

Does `rostopic pub ..` not work for you?

The following works for me:

```
rostopic pub -r 1 /some_topic std_msgs/Time 'data: { secs: 1, nsecs: 2 }'
```

---

Edit: just noticed this:

> I'd like to publish the current ROS time to a topic from the command line.

That would seem to be something else.

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to take the messages published on `/clock` and republish them on a different topic?

I haven't tested it, but [topic_tools/transform](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform) should be able to do that. It would have to transform a [rosgraph_msgs/Clock](http://docs.ros.org/api/rosgraph_msgs/html/msg/Clock.html) msg into a `std_msgs/Time` msg.

The documentation should help to construct the Python expression. #q261935 provides an example.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-11-07**:
Documentation is here: http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic#rostopic_command-line_tool